# css file name disappear after webpack bundle

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I use React with self-setting webpack

in general, we use chrome development tool to see css(or sass) in element, and we can also see css file name,

but, in my case,  I cannot see css file name in development tool, I can only see < style >, but I don't know which file it is

I think the trouble is in my webpack, but I don't know what's wrong with it,
hope someone can help me, thanks

here is my webpack setting:

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const webpack = require('webpack'); // to access built-in plugins

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'App': './react_source_code/App.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/react_component',
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: './react_component'
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false,
      maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
      maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules', 'react_source_code'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-env",
                                "@babel/preset-react"
                            ],
                            plugins: [
                                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                                "@babel/transform-runtime"
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
               test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
               use: [{
                   loader: 'file-loader',
                   options: {
                       name: '[name].[ext]',
                       outputPath: '/fonts/'
                   }
               }]
           },
           {
               test: /\.mp4$/,
               use: 'file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]',
           },
        ],
    },
};
```

and this is my react component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Yt.scss'

const Yt = () => (
  <section class='yt' id='yt'>
    <div class='section-outer-box'>
      <video class='mp4' src='images/video.mp4' controls autoplay loop muted></video>
    </div>
  </section>
)

export default Yt
```

and this is my index.html

```
<?php include_once "./common.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-TW">

<head>
  <?php include_once 'metaTag.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='App'></div>

  <script src="react_component/App.js"></script>
  <?php page_footer(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For developement build, webpack usually put the styles in style tag for faster debugging. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: so is there a way can let me see the file name??

Comment: You can configure webpack such that it can include the file name in the class name itself. So by just looking at the class name, you can get the filename.

Comment: not sure about that ??